# deleting multiple entry in database using checkbox php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, pdo

I am showing a list in my project the data is from a database i use php pdo to get the data now i want to have a function to delete multiple entry using checkbox i am doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227732/delete-multiple-rows-with-pdo-and-checkboxes-using-prepared-statements) tutorial i am doing the answer of john, but im getting an error saying

`Warning: PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in` line `$stmt->execute($id);`

this is the entire code

```
function ImageGalleryDelete(){
    global $dbh;
    if(!empty($_POST['checkbox'])){
        $bigimage = $_POST['checkbox'];
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM imagegallery WHERE id = ?");
        foreach ($bigimage as $id)
            $stmt->execute($id);

    }else{
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('big image is empty');
                window.location='dashboard.php';
                </script>";
                exit;
    }       
}
```

why am i getting that error? Any Help will be appreciated..

Comment: `why am i getting that error` - because `$id` is not an array. Capt. Obvious.

Comment: so you mean to say i should put it like this `$stmt->execute($bigimage );` bigimage here is array right?

Comment: ....... Please read the manual entry for [`PDOStatement::execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

Comment: `$bigimage` is array, but it doesn't suit. Read php manual, it's described there - http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php, example 3 explains everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint is already in the error message shown, feed an array with the correct format:

```
$bigimage = $_POST['checkbox'];
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM imagegallery WHERE id = :id");
                                                       //   ^ named placeholder
foreach ($bigimage as $id) {
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
                // ^ put an key value pair array inside with the designated named placeholder
                // along with the value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd typically write this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM imagegallery WHERE id = :id");
foreach ($bigimage as $id) {
    $stmt->execute(array(":id" => $id));
}
```

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote you just for the omitted `{}`.

Comment: And the other answer fixed it. You wouldn't leave an SQL injection vulnerability in code, would you? Why leave other glaring bad practices?

Comment: I also wouldn't assume $_POST['checkbox'] is sanitized, just a little out of context for the question